# Using atmosphere for GWT Comet

Tags: java, gwt, comet, long-polling

I was looking for a simple framework for implementing Comet for my GWT application.
I looked on gwt-rocket which seems to be non active, then on gwt-comet which is not active, then on atmosphere-gwt-comet which was moved into the atmosphere project, and finally - tried to actually download the gwt sample from atmosphere and work with it. :|

I added the atmosphere-gwt-server and atmosphere-gwt-client modules (version 0.8.6) to my project and tried to make the existing atmosphere sample to work.
I'm getting connection terminated exceptions all the time, and no messages. It seems that example doesn't post anything and not telling how to do it.

I cannot find any good JavaDocs or documents working with the this framework, nor any other active recommended frameworks.
Furthermore, I cannot understand which Comet method this atmosphere framework use - long poll or streaming? For my application it seems that long-poll is enough and I don't want to get into many problems / incompatibilities I read on the streaming method.

Can someone please recommend an easy solution? Sample? documentation?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Atmosphere not only supports long polling and streaming, but also websockets. I havent tried the GWT module for atmosphere but I can tell you that it's a quite polished framework and the main developer is active both at developing and at support. The main page of the project now is:

https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere

Here's the javadoc for the last version:

http://atmosphere.github.com/atmosphere/apidocs/

Also you can have a look at the blog the developer runs which contains lots of useful information:

http://jfarcand.wordpress.com/

And if you have any atmosphere-related questions, I recommend you to have a look here first and see if any of your questions have been answered before:

http://groups.google.com/group/atmosphere-framework?pli=1

Hope it helps :-) I encourage you to give Atmosphere a try, once you get used to it, it's awesome! Also have a look at the whitepaper available for download from the github page!